# UI5 Indexed DB: store variables and call them later

Tags: javascript, sapui5, indexeddb

I'm currently working on a app-project, in which data (in form of variables) should be stored offline, while using this app.

I have successfully created an `IndexedDB` database in my app as you can see from the following browser screenshot:

[image: Borwser Screenshot of IndexedDB]

I have created a signature pad where a user can draw their signature. I do not want to upload the signature image immediately to the server. Instead, I want to store the base64 string of the signature in IndexedDB. After storing it, I want to clear the signature pad and store the next signature image as a base64 string in IndexedDB, but avoid losing the string from the first signature.

I created the database with the following code. The variable `imagetxtb64` is the base64 string of the signature.

```
storestring: function () {
  var signpad = this.getView().byId("digitalSignatureId");
  var imagetxtb64 = signpad.getSignatureAsJpeg(); 

  var image = new Image();
  var element = document.createElement('a');

  image.src = imagetxtb64;

  var request = window.indexedDB.open("Offline Database Example", 1);
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
    var db = event.target.result;
    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("mydata");
  };
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to store the variable `imagetxtb64` in IndexedDB. And furthermore i want to have access to this variables later on.

Comment: " I don't know why this question is on hold?" -> Probably becuase the post does not contain enough information. Especially, please consider editing your question and add as many information as **text** (relevant : [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251)

Comment: @Pac0: now i have updated my question and put more information on it. I hope someone can help me

Comment: I would suggest adding some example (and very simplified, though still working) code that adds the variable, and example code that you expect to work that try to read the variables. Having actual example of code is something much better received on Stack Overflow, especially if you want your quetion to be reopened. (this code would correspond to what is meant by " [mcve] " in the above box ). 
For your information, this moderation is mostly community based. Once you edit your question, it goes through a review queue, where high-rep users can vote for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a new object in an object store, you would want to use either the put or add methods. Here is a brief example:

```
function putThing(db, thing, callback) {
  // Start a writable transaction on the object store containing things
  var transaction = db.transaction('things', 'readwrite');
  // Get the handle to the object store in the transaction
  var store = transaction.objectStore('things');

  // Listen for when the transaction commits (completes) so we can call the 
  // callback function to let the caller know the operate is done, both when 
  // it was done successfully, and when an error occurred.
  transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
    var error = undefined;
    callback(error, thing);
  };

  transaction.onerror = function(event) {
    var error = event.target.error;
    callback(error, thing);
  };

  // Insert or update the thing in the store
  store.put(thing);

  // extra note: you could also listen to when the request completes with an 
  // error or successfully, but keep in mind that when making actual changes 
  // like add/delete/update, your changes really only take place when the 
  // transaction completes, not the requests. that is why this example only 
  // cares about when the transaction completes and not the request. be careful,
  // a lot of 'toy' examples on the internet make this mistake of prematurely 
  // concluding the operation was successful by only looking at whether the
  // request completed and not the transaction. that shortcut is only correct 
  // when you are reading data (in a readonly transaction).
}

putThing(db, myThing, function myCallback(error, thing) {
  if(error) {
    console.log('problem storing thing', error, thing);
  } else {
    console.log('stored thing!', thing);
  }
});
```

This is a trivial operation that is well documented in several introductions to indexedDB. I highly recommend reading some [introductory documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB). This is also partly why your question is problematic, because this is one of the first things you can learn reading any introduction to indexedDB on the internet.

The second part of your question is that you want to store a new thing each time. So in that case you probably want to continually add new things to the same store.

By storing the data in the database, you will have access to it later. At any point in time later on you can connect to the database and load data from it. This is also rather trivial and thoroughly covered in pretty much any introduction to indexedDB on the internet.

Edit: this is a followup based on your comment.

So you are a storing a string variable, the base 64 encoding. if that is used as the key path then that distinctly identifies each object in the store. So you want to instead make sure a new entry is stored when executing your function a second time, you probably want to store something different. instead, use an id property. set the id property as the keypath. set the auto-increment flag on the id property when creating the object store.

then, do not set the id property in your object before storing it. then store it. it will get assigned a new id as a result of storing. each time you call put with an object without its keypath, it will get inserted. each time you call put with an object *with* its keypath, it will get replaced.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have now successfully created a indexedDB with content of my variable! ... now i want to execute my function in the same windows several times, but if i execute the function the second time, no new entry would be in the database. (FYI: i set the keyPath to autoIncrement: true). Do you have a solution for this?